# Extracting and rolling up data from XML documents in C#

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm

I'm trying to extract data from an XML document and roll-up the data based on time in C#.

For instance - I have the following XML documents:

Document 1:

```
                "<HourlyTotals>" +
                "<Data>" +
                "<Time>08:00</Time>" +
                "<NetSales>200.25</NetSales>" +
                "<NetReturns>15.25</NetReturns>" +
                "<NetIncome>185.00</NetIncome>" +
                "<CustomerCount>15</CustomerCount>" +
                "<PercentOfIncome>3</PercentOfIncome>" +
                "</Data>" +
                "<Data>" +
                "<Time>08:15</Time>" +
                "<NetSales>100.25</NetSales>" +
                "<NetReturns>15.25</NetReturns>" +
                "<NetIncome>85.00</NetIncome>" +
                "<CustomerCount>2</CustomerCount>" +
                "<PercentOfIncome>1.5</PercentOfIncome>" +
                "</Data>" +
                 "<Data>" +
                "<Time>08:30</Time>" +
                "<NetSales>100.25</NetSales>" +
                "<NetReturns>15.25</NetReturns>" +
                "<NetIncome>85.00</NetIncome>" +
                "<CustomerCount>2</CustomerCount>" +
                "<PercentOfIncome>1.5</PercentOfIncome>" +
                "</Data>" +
                "<Data>" +
                "<Time>10:00</Time>" +
                "<NetSales>100.25</NetSales>" +
                "<NetReturns>10.25</NetReturns>" +
                "<NetIncome>176.00</NetIncome>" +
                "<CustomerCount>10</CustomerCount>" +
                "<PercentOfIncome>1</PercentOfIncome>" +
                "</Data>" +
                "</HourlyTotals>"
```

**Please ignore the quotes and '+' : It's because of the fact that I was trying to create fake XML data and pass it as a string to a list in C#.**

Document 2:

```
            "<HourlyTotals>" +
            "<Data>" +
            "<Time>08:00</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>100.25</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>10.25</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>176.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>10</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>1</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
            "<Data>" +
            "<Time>08:15</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>120.00</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>11.00</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>54.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>5</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>2.3</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
             "<Data>" +
            "<Time>08:30</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>160.11</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>17.25</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>34.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>4</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>3.2</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
            "<Data>" +
            "<Time>09:15</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>100.25</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>10.25</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>176.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>10</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>1</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
            "<Data>" +
            "<Time>10:00</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>100.25</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>10.25</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>176.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>10</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>1</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
            "</HourlyTotals>"
```

Document 3:

```
            "<HourlyTotals>" +
            "<Data>" +
            "<Time>08:00</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>22.25</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>21.25</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>122.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>3</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>6</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
            "<Data>" +
            "<Time>08:15</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>174.00</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>16.00</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>68.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>2</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>0.2</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
             "<Data>" +
            "<Time>08:30</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>99.00</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>88.00</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>69.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>6</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>9</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
            "<Data>" +
            "<Time>09:30</Time>" +
            "<NetSales>100.25</NetSales>" +
            "<NetReturns>10.25</NetReturns>" +
            "<NetIncome>176.00</NetIncome>" +
            "<CustomerCount>10</CustomerCount>" +
            "<PercentOfIncome>1</PercentOfIncome>" +
            "</Data>" +
            "</HourlyTotals>"
```

I want to roll-up the NetSales, NetReturns, NetIncome, CustomerCount and PercentOfIncome values by time. For instance, time 8:00 should have the value of 
 **322.75** (200.25 + 100.25 + 22.25) as the NetSales value and so on..

The time node values can range from 8:00 to 23:45. I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to extract all the time intervals and roll up the values based on them.

So far, I have written code to extract the data of individual nodes from the XML:

```
foreach (var selector in fakeXML)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(selector);
            var data = doc.Descendants("Data");
            var result1 = from q in data
                          select new
                          {
                              Time = q.Element("Time").Value,
                              NetSales = q.Element("NetSales").Value,
                              NetReturns = q.Element("NetReturns").Value,
                              NetIncome = q.Element("NetIncome").Value,
                              CustCount = q.Element("CustomerCount").Value,
                              PercentOfIncome = q.Element("PercentOfIncome").Value
                          }

        }
```

fakeXML is a list of strings which contains the individual XML documents as strings.

This code just allows me to extract individual nodes from the XML documents.

I'm not able to figure out an effective way to roll it up based on the value of the time node. Any leads on how to proceed would be really great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After you have all the data. group by time and sum of the values in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have all the data. Group them by `Time` and then `Sum` up the values in each group.

```
var data = fakeXML.SelectMany(selector => {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(selector);
    return from q in doc.Descendants("Data")
           select new {
               Time = q.Element("Time").Value,
               NetSales = (decimal)q.Element("NetSales"),
               NetReturns = (decimal)q.Element("NetReturns"),
               NetIncome = (decimal)q.Element("NetIncome"),
               CustCount = (int)q.Element("CustomerCount"),
               PercentOfIncome = (double)q.Element("PercentOfIncome")
           };
});

var summary = data.GroupBy(d => d.Time)
    .Select(g => new {
        Time = g.Key,
        NetSales = g.Sum(d => d.NetSales),
        NetReturns = g.Sum(d => d.NetReturns),
        NetIncome = g.Sum(d => d.NetIncome),
        CustCount = g.Sum(d => d.CustCount),
    });
```

Each item in the summary collection would have the totals by time.

Comment: I wouldn't use `decimal.Parse()`, `int.Parse()` or `double.Parse()` since those are locale-specific.  Instead use the API already provided, e.g. for `decimal` either [`XmlConvert.ToDecimal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) or just [cast directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353285(v=vs.110).aspx) to a decimal: `NetSales = (decimal)q.Element("NetSales"),`

Comment: @dbc fixed. Thanks again for the advice.